# How to connect on premise oracle database in AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, on-premises-instances

Am looking to connect to on premise oracle database and extract the data to EC2 instance and perform transformations and load into RDS instance.
What would be the necessary steps to connect on premise or external application to AWS.

Any suggestions and assistance will be helpful.

Comment: A lot of networking stuff is required. How that networking setup looks like depends entirely on your existing network and potentially already existing aws infrastructure.

Comment: @luk2302. Thanks for the key points. Would you be able to suggest any document to review on

Comment: https://www.v500.com/aws/ https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/scenario-onprem.html https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/cross-domain-solutions/connecting-on-premises-infrastructure.html https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/connect-data-center-to-aws/ (it is a VERY broad and complicated topic)

Comment: Probably better to push an export from the on-prem DB to S3 and from there to wherever it's needed. Or mirror/sync the DB to an on-AWS read replica.